# R Restrict a cycle

Tags: r

I want to restrict the for cycle to only perform task if `j` is in some range of i (`3` units, for example).
I tried the following piece of code:

```
a <- c(1:100)
b <- c(1:100)

k1 <- length(a)
k2 <- length(b)

for (i in 1:k1){
  for (j in 1:k2){
    if (j>=i-3 & j<=i+3){
      c<-c(a+b)
    }
  }
}
```

What I pretended was
`if i=1, j={1,2,3}, if i=6, j={1,2,3,4,5,6}`

This doesn´t really work since, `j` and `i` will end up running from 1 to 100.

Comment: Right now, it is a little hard to understand what you want. What do you expect to happen and the end of this code if it ran like you wanted it to run? Right now, the value `a+b` is repeatedly assigned to `c`. (Also, it is typically called a for *loop* rather than a *cycle*.)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. you´re right, assigning it repeatedly is a mistake. Matthew Lundberg answered my question perfectly on the doubts I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, the problem is that you are looping through 100 combinations of `j`, when only three to seven are actually useful.

If this is correct, you can loop through seven iterations of `j` and filter for values that are positive and within bounds:

```
width <- 3
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  for (j in (i-width):(i+width)) {
    if (j > 0 && j <= length(b)) {
      # Do something
    }
  }
}
```

When you `# Do something` in your code, I would advise not assigning to a variable named `c`.

Comment: Thanks, that´s very good.  You´re right, that was a mistake and I corrected it already!